# How do I display a PDF Named Destination in Windows Server 2012 or 2016 in default Edge Browser from a .net C# app?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, microsoft-edge

Language: C# .net 
I have tried the Adobe method which requires Adobe Reader. Even it does not work well - I want to open the file to a destination, then change the destination as the user clicks on a Context Help icon. I do NOT want multiple new windows to clutter the screen.

I am trying to open a PDF to a named destination using the default PDF reader in Windows 2012 Server. (and same in windows server 2016). I don't want to force users to install Adobe PDF Reader. I want to use the default browser-based reader on a standard install.

WHen I use the Adobe method, if I use the n flag, I get a new window every time - annoying. If I don't use the n flag, I can open ONE window; all subsequent calls to change the topic are ignored.

Comment: if you know the name of the PDF you can try this. using System.Diagnostics;Process.Start( @"C:\Users\Desktop\Sample.txt" );

Answer (score 0):

Open the Windows Setting, click the Apps, select the Default Apps option and choose the "Choose default apps by file type", then find the .pdf file name and choose the Microsoft Edge as default apps to view the file. like this.

[image]

Then, using the following code to open the pdf file using Edge browser:

```
Process.Start("file path. such as: 'file:///C:/Users/XXX/Downloads/pdf.pdf'");
```

From your description, it seems that the pdf file is located on the remote server, I think you could download to local folder first, then using the above code to display the PDF file.